# Is there any way to update DynamoDB item as a batch without overwriting(not put_item, which overwrites) in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Is there any way to update_item() the DynamoDB table with a batch of items? Or any workarounds in Python for this?

```
response = table.update_item(
       Key={
        'ReleaseNumber': releaseNumber,
        'Timestamp': result[0]['Timestamp']
    },
    UpdateExpression="set Sanity = :r",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':r': 'false',
    },
    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW")
```

Here is the sample code that I'm using. But this is just a single item only. I need the same for multiple items.

Comment: No, update operations are always on a single item.

Comment: @Maurice you should post that comment as answer so that the original poster can accept as answer.

Comment: is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @Jens - So far none of my "no this is not supported" answers have ever been accepted by the OP, but I'm willing to try again...

Comment: @Maurice that's too bad. But at least I can give you an upvote to reward you with those sweet +10 ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `UpdateItem` API always operates on a single item. There is no way to update multiple items like this or batch this operation.

If you can replace the item instead of updating it, you can use `BatchPutItem`, but that would be a different operation.